# Regex to find string and backslashes

Tags: regex, go

I have these strings and they can come in a variety of ways such as:

`id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen, value=34` and `id=Code\\ Cache,value=22` etc.

I would like a regex that would extract anything after the `=` to the `,` so basically: `PS\\ Old\\ Gen` and `Code\\ Cache` etc.

I have written the following regex but can't seem to get the last word before the `,`.

`(([a-zA-z]+)\\{2})+`

Any thoughts? This is for go language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and capture your text from group1,

```
id=([^,=]*),
```

**Explanation:**

- `id=` - Matches `id=` literally
- `([^,=]*)` - Matches any character except `,` or `=` zero or more times and captures in first grouping pattern
- `,` - Matches a comma

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ypsR4t/2)**

Sample Go codes,

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`id=([^,=]*),`)
var str = `id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen, value=34 id=Code\\ Cache,value=22`

res := re.FindAllStringSubmatch(str, -1)
for i := range res {
    fmt.Printf("Match: %s\n", res[i][1])
}
```

Prints,

```
Match: PS\\ Old\\ Gen
Match: Code\\ Cache
```

Comment: But I've got other strings such as area=Hello, and its picking them up. I just want to pick up any String that begins with an id which contains a blackslash on it

Comment: @kjvf: Well, if you carefully read your post, you have written this "that would extract anything after the = to the ," and I have exactly followed what you wrote and gave you the solution. Now as you wrote in your comment that you only need text followed by `id=`, my regex just needs little change and instead of just `=` it needs to be `id=` and that will work perfectly for you. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @kjvf: Updated my post to ensure your intended text is preceded by `id=` instead of just `=`. Check and let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Does something like `id=([^,]+),` do the trick?

Capture group no.1 will contain your match. See this in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/2oW9Mx/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about that? **SEE** [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/fsp3FS/2)

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(?mi)id=([^,]+)`)
    var str = `id=PS\\ Old\\ Gen, value=34 and id=Code\\ Cache,value=22`

    for i, match := range re.FindAllString(str, -1) {
        fmt.Println(match, "found at index", i)
    }
}
```